# Protect an object when used as parameter input

Tags: c#

When I use an instance of an object as the parameter of a method, I want to protect it and its properties from being changed in the method that is called. I looked at the `in` parameter modifier, but this seems to only protect the reference of the object. As such the properties of the instance can still be changed.

Is there a parameter modifier that protects the full object? If not what would be my alternatives, perhaps some kind of linting solution to at least protect from my own mistakes? (I prefer not deep clone the instance every time it's passed to a method)

*For reference I am using .net core 3.1, c# and my IDE is Visual Studio Code.*

Comment: The only reliable way is to design parameter objects as immutable ones. There is no generic way to tell "this object graph is read-only".

Comment: Reducing dependencies on mutable state is a really important thing so it's good that you're thinking about it. Unfortunately there is no magic keyword that will do what you ask. But there are ways to write your code that will accomplish the same thing, e.g. if you use immutable [record](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record) types, or if you pass individual values instead of the whole object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an immutable version of your class:

```
public class Example
{
   public int Prop1 {get;set;}
   public string Prop2 {get;set;}
}

public class ImmutableExample
{
   private readonly Example value;

   public int Prop1 => value.Prop1;
   public string Prop2 => value.Prop2;

   public ImmutableExample(Example value)
   {
      this.value = value;
   }
}
```

You won't copy the whole object, but only create a new reference to the old object (this is the same way as `AsReadonly()` of `List<T>` works). If you use your immutable version of your class in your method, you have achieved what you wanted. Here is some example usage:

```
public void DoStuff(Example input)
{
   DoStuff(new ImmutableExample(input));
}

public void DoStuff(ImmutableExample input)
{
   // input.Prop1 = 5 will be impossible
}
```

Another option is to declare an interface which provides only the getters:

```
public class Example : IExample
{
   public int Prop1 {get;set;}
   public string Prop2 {get;set;}
}

public interface IExample
{
    int Prop1 {get;}
    string Prop2 {get;}
}
```

If you require the interface for the type of your method parameter, you won't be able to change the values of your properties of the object in your class. Usage would be:

```
public void DoStuff(IExample input)
{
    // input.Prop1 = 5 will be impossible
}
```

Comment: Thanks @SomeBody these are useful patterns.  My main concern is that I have very large classes and different parts of the system needs to be able to change the values of the object graph.  Which would make both solutions very time consuming to implement and maintain.  I'll consider these patterns vs options like deep cloning the graph before passing it to the method.

Comment: In that case, you could use the first approach and provide all properties with setters. In your constructor, you give somehow the information which properties can be changed (e.g. with a lot of bool variables) and in the setters, you check whether this property can be changed and throw an exception if it's not possible. But this will only be a runtime, not a compile time check.

Answer (score 3):

Nope. If the instances class provides for mutable state, there is no way to protect it when used as a parameter. That also does not really make sense. The implementer of that method specified that they want to receive an object of a certain type for a reason.

Comment: *"method [...] want to receive an object of a certain type for a reason"* Thanks Eric, I pass the full object graph as the method needs the full context.  But the method is only allowed to change 1 property of the object graph.  So as simplified example `car.GearBox = gearboxFactory.ReplaceGearBox(car)` where `ReplaceGearBox(Car car)` needs to know loads of properties of `car` to build the correct `GearBox`.  But I don't want it to alter anything in `car`.  I'll consider refactoring to make the classes immutable.